# Max Value in a Data Frame with Groupby using idmax()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I have a dataframe that has 10 columns.

I used this code to filter to the rows I want: basically, the rows where the Revision Date is less than the cutoff date (declared variable) and the Job Title is in the provided list.

```
aggregate = df.loc[(df['RevisionDate']<= cutoff_date) & (df['JobTitle'].isin(['Production Control Clerk','Customer Service Representative III, Data Entry Operator I','Accounting Clerk II','General Clerk III','Technical Instructor']))]
```

Then, I need to group them by the column WD (there are multiple of these), and then by Job Title (again, multiple of these). So I did that by:

```
aggregate1 = aggregate.groupby(['WD','JobTitle'])
```

This produces a dataframe object that has the required rows, and still all 10 columns.

Then, from this smaller dataframe, I need to pull out only the rows with the highest (max) Revision Number.

```
aggregate1 = aggregate.max('RevisionNumber')
```

However, this last step produces a dataframe, but with only 3 of the columns: WD, Job Title and Revision Number. I need ALL 10 of the columns.

Based on other questions I've seen posted here, I have tried to use idmax():

```
df2 = aggregate.loc[aggregate.groupby(['WD','JobTitle'])['RevisionNumber'].idmax()]
```

but I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'idmax'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey Chris, thank you for that! that worked perfectly. If you change your comment into an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you sort first, you can take the top row of each group

```
aggregate.sort_values(by='RevisionNumber', ascending=False).groupby(['WD','JobTitle']).head(1)
```